# Tablayout with camera button like Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I wanted to implement a tablayout similar to the Android WhatsApp app.

[image]

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: And what specific problems have you encountered?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

After your "setupWithViewPager" add "tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.your_camera_icon)"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you just want to know how to change the text to an icon like in your picture or if you don't know how to make a tablayout.

If you don't know how to make a tablayout in general I suggest you to google "tablayout" ;) There are tons of good tutorials for example this short one here: https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a

I you use Fragments with a ViewPager and the tablayout element you won't need much code for a basic functionality.

If you already have a working tablayout you could make your own tablayout design. Here is a short description how to achieve that: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout#styling-the-tablayout